# lodash: deep copy object but not all properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there any way to copy an object with lodash, but not all properties.
The only way I know is manually copying it property by property

wanted e.g.:

```
var obj = {
    a: 'name',
    b: [1,2,3],
    c: {
        z: 'surname',
        x: []
    },
    d: {
        y: 'surname2',
        w: []
    }
};
```

and the result be like

```
var copy_obj = {
    b: [1,2,3],
    c: {
        z: 'surname',
        x: []
    }
};
```

Edit:
I finally opted for:

```
var blacklist = ['a','d'];
_.cloneDeep(_.omit(obj, blacklist));
```

Comment: Look into `pick` and `omit`.

Comment: If you have solved the problem yourself, please put that up as an answer, not an edit to the question. If you want, you can then accept that answer.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

```
var blacklist = ['a','d'];
_.cloneDeep(_.omit(obj, blacklist));
```

Comment: Why did you copy my answer word for word and mark it as correct?

Comment: @Chris: To be fair, [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36612253/1430156) was from April 14, while the OP already wrote this very code (as an [edit to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36604403/2)) on April 13, before probably copying *that* snippet into a new answer (as suggested by [a commenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604403#comment60825938_36604403)).

Comment: Fair, just seems odd. Was curious if there was something he found in his answer that makes it more correct - for future readers of this question/answer

Answer (score 27):

The `omit` serves almost this exact purpose:

```
_.cloneDeep(_.omit(obj, blacklist));
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c639m9L2/

Comment: Note from the Lodash docs:
"This method [i.e. `_.omit`] is considerably slower than `_.pick`."

Comment: can someone add this above _.clonedeep...,  var blacklist = ['a','d'];    its a pretty important line, the queue edit request is full

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [pick](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) function:

```
_.pick(obj, 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: Assuming the OP wants a deep copy, as suggested by the question title, this will not do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the second parameter to `JSON.stringify` to do this.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, ['b', 'c']))
```

Comment: Not my favourite but deserves some credit for using vanilla JS while the other answers all require lodash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of **assign** and **pick**

```
Object.assign(copy_obj, _.pick(obj, ['b', 'c']));
```

In this way if **copy_obj** has other properties you don't override them.

Comment: It's a fair point to show how to preserve props from `copy_obj`. However, this is only a shallow copy of the the props from `obj`. If you require a deep copy of them, you will want to use `_.deepClone` as well. I.e. `Object.assign(copy_obj, _.deepClone(_.pick(obj, ['b', 'c'])));`